# Getting SOMETIMES wrong @@rowcount after INSERT (..) SELECT.. (SQL-server 2014)

Tags: sql-server

In M$ SQL server 2014 (v.12.0.4100.1):
I'm trying to copy from one table (~3'500'000'000 rows) to another in batches using @@rowcount.
Both tables have unique index on ([timestamp],[NumericID]).

Problem is that after some successful loops I'm getting primary key violation like:

> ErrorNumber   ErrorSeverity   ErrorState  ErrorLine   ErrorProcedure  ErrorMessage:
>   2627  14  1   52  NULL    Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_DataHist_2'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DataHist_2'. The duplicate
>   key value is (Jul 14 2014  4:27PM, 5011).

The key values are always different. The error occurs after different number of loops, seems randomly.
It seems that SQL statement SOMETIMES returns @@rowcount = 0.
I can't figure out why it happens. Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
-- copy data from DataHist to DataHist_2
/* SRC table def:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataHist](
    [ID] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [NumericID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [BadQ] [BIT] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DataHist_BadQ]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [Quality]  AS (CASE ISNULL([BadQ],(0)) WHEN (0) THEN (1) ELSE (0) END),
    [Value]  [VARCHAR](8000)
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DataHist] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
)
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DataHist_Time_NumID] ON [dbo].[DataHist]
(
    [NumericID] ASC,
    [TimeStamp] ASC
) 
*/
/* Dest table:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataHist_2](
[TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[NumericID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Value] [varchar](8000) NULL,
[BadQ] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DataHist_2_BadQ]  DEFAULT (NULL),
[Quality]  AS (case isnull([BadQ],(0)) when (0) then (1) else (0) end),
CONSTRAINT [PK_DataHist_2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [TimeStamp] ASC,
   [NumericID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) -- ON [DataHistFG]
) -- ON [DataHistFG]
*/

BEGIN TRY
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

PRINT 'copy data from DataHist to DataHist_2';
PRINT GETUTCDATE();

DECLARE @nextID BIGINT = 1;
DECLARE @r INT ,
    @N INT = 1000000;
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @t0 DATETIME;
SET @r = 1;
-- find where to re-start copying:
SET @nextID = ( SELECT TOP ( 1 )
                        ID
                FROM    dbo.DataHist DH
                WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                     FROM   dbo.DataHist_2 DH2
                                     WHERE  DH.TimeStamp = DH2.TimeStamp
                                            AND DH.NumericID = DH2.NumericID )
                ORDER BY DH.ID
              );

PRINT @nextID;
PRINT GETUTCDATE();
-- insert in batches of @N:
WHILE @r > 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        SET @t0 = GETUTCDATE();

        INSERT  INTO dbo.DataHist_2
                ( TimeStamp ,
                  NumericID ,
                  BadQ ,
                  Value
                ) 
                SELECT TOP ( @N )
                        TimeStamp ,
                        NumericID ,
                        BadQ ,
                        Value
                FROM    dbo.DataHist 
                WHERE   ID >= @nextID
                ORDER BY ID 

        SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;
        SET @nextID = @nextID + @r;
        SET @s = 'nextID=' + CAST(@nextID AS VARCHAR(30)) + ', t='
            + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @t0, GETUTCDATE()) AS VARCHAR(1000));
        PRINT @s;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END;

PRINT GETUTCDATE();
PRINT 'END';

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
PRINT 'Catch Exception'
IF @@trancount > 0 
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Rolling back transaction.';
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;
EXEC usp_GetErrorInfo;
END CATCH;
```

Comment: Why are you re-setting the `id`?  Just use an `identity` column.

Comment: Is your question that why @@rowcount is 0 when the insert wasn't successful because of primary key violation?

Comment: did you check how many rows with id 5011 are in the source table?

Comment: Do you have triggers? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9fca7f75-3ab3-42ac-98a9-89a8e309c19e/rowcount-trigger?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: Did you check your source for duplications ?

Comment: Looking at the source, I fail to see how `@@ROWCOUNT = 0` would lead to a PK violation. Doesn't the loop exit when there are no rows, so there would be no more inserts to violate the key. Are other processes writing to `do.DataHist`. Without knowing the system, that looks like a culprit, if `ID` of an already copied row changed so that it ended up being copied again.

Comment: Also, identity columns are not guaranteed to be gap free. Your code is relying on `ID` to be gap free. But since it fails in different IDs that might not be an issue.

Comment: @Shannon: Yeah, there is a lot of code here, sorry. I just wanted to report all the details. 
The essence of the problem is here, IMHO:
in the `INSERT` there is `WHERE ID >= @nextID`. This `@nextID` is incremented by `@@ROWCOUNT` directly after the previous insert. Sometimes, (after arbitrary number of loops!) I see the error: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_DataHist_2". I think it could be that `@nextID` has not been incremented right and the `INSERT` therefore tried  to insert (partially) the same batch again.

Comment: No processes modify src and no triggers on dest tables

Comment: When you say the key values are always different, are you starting from scratch, from an empty destination table? If not I think your problem is likely to be holes in the ID sequence. For example `@N` of 2, and `@NextID` of 101. A hole at 102, so that IDs 101 & 103 are copied. `@@ROWCOUNT` is 2, `@NextID + @@ROWCOUNT` is 103, and record 103 is copied again, resulting in a PK violation. On restart, the initial value for `@StartID` is above  103.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance: You solve it, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @Shannon Severance suggested, the problem was "holes in the ID sequence" of the source table.

Solved by setting @nextID this way:

`SET @nextID =  (SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM dbo.DataHist_2); 
-- was: SET @nextID = @nextID + @r;`

(ID column was added to the destination table and copied from src.)

Thank you, Shannon

Answer (score -1):

Dude, @@rowcount is correct and equal to 1 always.
PLease check this code for more clarity:

-- copy data from DataHist to DataHist_2
                /* SRC table def:
                CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#DataHist](
                    [ID] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                    [TimeStamp] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
                    [NumericID] [INT] NOT NULL,
                    [BadQ] [BIT] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DataHist_BadQ]  DEFAULT (NULL),
                    [Quality]  AS (CASE ISNULL([BadQ],(0)) WHEN (0) THEN (1) ELSE (0) END),
                    [Value]  VARCHAR
                 CONSTRAINT [PK_DataHist] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
                (
                    [ID] ASC
                )
                )

```
            --SELECT * FROM [#DataHist]
            CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DataHist_Time_NumID] ON [dbo].[#DataHist]
            (
                [NumericID] ASC,
                [TimeStamp] ASC
            ) 
            */
            /* Dest table:
            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#DataHist_2](
            [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
            [NumericID] [int] NOT NULL,
            [Value] [varchar](8000) NULL,
            [BadQ] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DataHist_2_BadQ]  DEFAULT (NULL),
            [Quality]  AS (case isnull([BadQ],(0)) when (0) then (1) else (0) end),
            CONSTRAINT [PK_DataHist_2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            (
               [TimeStamp] ASC,
               [NumericID] ASC
            )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) -- ON [DataHistFG]
            ) -- ON [#DataHistFG]
            */

            BEGIN TRY
            SET XACT_ABORT ON;
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            PRINT 'copy data from DataHist to DataHist_2';
            PRINT GETUTCDATE();

            DECLARE @nextID BIGINT = 1;
            DECLARE @r INT ,
                @N INT = 1000000;
            DECLARE @s VARCHAR(1000);
            DECLARE @t0 DATETIME;
            SET @r = 1;
            --// find where to re-start copying:
            SET @nextID = ( SELECT TOP ( 1 )
                                    ID
                            FROM    #DataHist DH
                            WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                                 FROM   #DataHist_2 DH2
                                                 WHERE  DH.TimeStamp = DH2.TimeStamp
                                                        AND DH.NumericID = DH2.NumericID )
                            ORDER BY DH.ID
                          );

            PRINT @nextID;
            PRINT GETUTCDATE();
            -- insert in batches of @N:
            WHILE @r > 0
                BEGIN
                    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

                    SET @t0 = GETUTCDATE();

                    INSERT  INTO #DataHist_2
                            ( TimeStamp ,
                              NumericID ,
                              BadQ ,
                              Value
                            ) 
                            SELECT TOP ( @N )
                                    TimeStamp ,
                                    NumericID ,
                                    BadQ ,
                                    Value
                            FROM    #DataHist 
                            WHERE   ID >= @nextID
                            ORDER BY ID 

                    SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;
                    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
                    SET @nextID = @nextID + @r;
                    SET @s = 'nextID=' + CAST(@nextID AS VARCHAR(30)) + ', t='
                        + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @t0, GETUTCDATE()) AS VARCHAR(1000));
                    PRINT @s;

                    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

            END;

            PRINT GETUTCDATE();
            PRINT 'END';

            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT 'Catch Exception'
            IF @@trancount > 0 
                BEGIN
                    PRINT 'Rolling back transaction.';
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                END;
            EXEC usp_GetErrorInfo;
            END CATCH;
```

Comment: *Dude*, if the statement triggers a trigger, @@rowcount will be wrong. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9fca7f75-3ab3-42ac-98a9-89a8e309c19e/rowcount-trigger?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: No, @@rowcount is mostly = # of inserted rows, BUT not always. And that is a problem.
No triggers down the line.

Comment: What is your answer? I see a lot of code, but no idea what you are trying to say with it.

Comment: @Shannon: If you check the code , I am just selecting 'SELECT @@ROWCOUNT' to prove that the value of @@RowCOUNT is same everytime.